# Git - Models with composition and branches

Tags: git, model-view-controller, git-branch, git-flow

According to @nvie's [definition of feature branch](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), I think that every class of a project should be a feature branch.

For example:

```
git checkout -b car develop
git checkout -b wheel develop
git checkout -b engine develop
```

And in each branch, I define the implementation of the classes related to properly named one, such as `wheel`, `wheel_dao`, `wheel_composite`.

In this case, `car` is the owner of `wheel` and `engine`. So I guess that merging the `wheel` and `engine` branches into car's would be correct.

```
W---\
     \
------C
     /
E---/
```

But I found that this could be terrible due to the fact that `engine` and `wheel` will still get new commits, so every time a commit is added to those branches, I will to merge it again into `car`.

I would like you to share with me an article where I can find more information about using git with models (MVC maybe?). Or perhaps you guys can tell me a more appropriate way to branch a composition.

Comment: I think you´re making a wrong assumption that classes are equal to features. Although you most often create new classes when implementing a new feature, a new class does not constitute a feature until it provides new functionality. You model is really flawed when you get to more complex cases that require several classes to solve - it would mean constantly switching branches and rebasing while working on the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your first impression

> According to @nvie's definition of feature branch, I think that every
>   class of a project should be a feature branch.

is surely off the mark.  [The article states](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model#feature-branches)

> The essence of a feature branch is that it exists as long as the
>   feature is in development, but will eventually be merged back into
>   *develop*

And [regarding the *develop* branch](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model#the-main-branches)

> We consider *origin/develop* to be the main branch where the source code
>   of HEAD always reflects a state with the latest delivered development
>   changes for the next release. Some would call this the “integration
>   branch”. **This is where any automatic nightly builds are built from**.

So strictly by this definition, if you restrict a feature branch to a single class, you must restrict all changes to that class to be non-breaking (of the build), or else you could not merge the *develop* branch directly into it.

Now, if you're following the Model-View-Controller pattern, you should have unit tests and ideally integration tests.  Whenever you add a feature, you should want to know when it's complete, so each feature should introduce new tests or modify existing ones.

So to answer your question, the (usually) appropriate way to branch a composition is to decide which tests describe the feature and include only the changes verifiable by those tests.

Try to believe that the usefulness of your git workflow is largely dictated by your testing workflow.